# Sonar.Branch parameter is throwing error in SonarQube 5.0

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

**People,
With new SonarQube version for C# plugin -Dsonar.branch=X parameter is throwing error. The error is as follows:-**

Sonar failed with error: 'ERROR: Error during Sonar runner executionERROR: Unable to execute SonarERROR: Caused by: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@56b0f44f[key=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,deprecatedKey=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,path=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,dir=Aspects,filename=MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,language=C#]'ERROR: Caused by: Resource org.sonar.api.resources.File@56b0f44f[key=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,deprecatedKey=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,path=Aspects/MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,dir=Aspects,filename=MethodPerformanceAttribute.cs,language=C#] was not found in InputPath cacheERROR

**This error goes away and sonar run is succeessful if i remove the -Dsonar.branch parameter. Can someone provide more information on this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in SonarQube 5.1, see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6250 for additional details.